# В окне при наведение на любой элемент курсор включает "фоновый режим", как это исправить?

Tags: c#, wpf, cursor

По какой причине это может происходить? Раньше у меня этого не было.

*Сделал фото, так как скрин убирает курсор.*
[image]

Comment: Ctrl+Shit+F на проекте и ищите слово "Cursor"

Comment: @АндрейNOP Действительно, всё оказалось проще, чем я думал. У меня зачем-то в Gird стоял cursor="Appstarting". Спасибо большое.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> на проекте и ищите слово "Cursor"

Comment: Это ответ на вопрос?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Именно